# why proto buffer no date data type?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto3

I am using node, I am curious why proto buffer there is no date data type?

I am using sequelizejs ORM which I define a date field:

```
tranTime: DataTypes.DATE
```

MYSQL database is save as DateTime.

Which data type should I use? Anyone use datetime with GRPC?

Comment: There's a Date (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in place, and there's a 3rd party ORM utility (https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) in place as well.  I believe you can use Date in your program while can be properly mapped to real dbms field type.

Comment: I am talking about protocol buffer. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use an int64 unix timestamp and then convert it. Date formats can be different between languages but a unix timestamp would be the same as an int64 or unsigned int32

Comment: Yes, this is what I recommend (as the author of proto2).